Fixed point formula of Atiyah and Singer applied to a Dirac operator on a spin manifold
Let $G$ be a compact Lie group acting by orientation-preserving isometries on a compact even-dimensional spin manifold $X$, and assume that the $G$-action preserves the spin structure of $X$, so that it commutes with the Dirac operator $D:\Gamma(V^+)\to \Gamma(V^-)$ on the complex spinor bundle.
For $g\in G$ let $X^g\subset X$ denote the fixed-point-set of $g:X\to X$. Then according to the Lefschetz fixed point formula of Atiyah-Singer, we have $$\text{Spin}(g,X)(:=\text{ind}_g(D))=(-1)^k \dfrac{\textrm{ch}_g(V^+(T)-V^-(T)) \text{td}(T^g\otimes \Bbb C)}{e(T^g)\text{ch}_g(\Lambda_{-1} N^g\otimes \Bbb C)} [X^g] $$
(cf. p.169 of Shanahan's book The Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem.) Here $T=TX$, $T^g=TX^g$, $N^g=NX^g$ (the normal bundle of $X^g$ in $X$), and $k=(\dim X^g) /2$.
For a twisted Dirac operator $D^E:\Gamma(V^+\otimes E)\to \Gamma(V^-\otimes E)$, we have a similar formula
$$\text{ind}_g(D^E))=(-1)^k \dfrac{\textrm{ch}_g(V^+(T)-V^-(T)) \text{td}(T^g\otimes \Bbb C)}{e(T^g)\text{ch}_g(\Lambda_{-1} N^g\otimes \Bbb C)}\cdot \text{ch}_g(E) [X^g] $$
On the other hand, according to the last paragraph of p.349 of https://bpb-us-e2.wpmucdn.com/faculty.sites.uci.edu/dist/3/246/files/2011/03/23_PseudoFreeOrbifolds.pdf, in the case $X^g=\{\text{point}\}=y$ we have $$ 
\text{ind}_g(D^E)=\dfrac{\text{ch}_g(V_+-V_-)}{\text{ch}_g(\Lambda_{-1})}(T\otimes \Bbb C) \cdot \text{ch}_g(E) [\text{point}],
$$
where $T$ is the tangent space at the point $y$.
(In this paper the Dirac operator has coefficients in $V_- \otimes \mathfrak{g}_E$.)
My question is: Are these two different formulas the same? I cannot understand why $(T\otimes \Bbb C)$ is involved in the second formula; it is not even a cohomology class.

I can only guess that $(T\otimes\mathbb C)$ should be added both to the numerator and the denominator, giving the vector bundles the classes are taken of. For isolated fixpoints, $TM=N$. Then $Td/e=1$ for the zero-dimensional bundle $T^g$. So, the formulas agree.
